# Get keys from php array and use SQL WERE .. IN .. clause to filter results

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have following dynamic $array1:

```
    array(6) { [1]=> string(5) "false" 
               [2]=> string(5) "true" 
               [3]=> string(5) "false" 
               [4]=> string(5) "false" 
               [5]=> string(5) "true" 
               [10]=> string(5) "false" 
             }
```

1. What I would like to do to use loop to create $array2 with $array1 keys where values = "true". 
   So in the end I have:

```
$array2 = (2, 5);
```

2. And then use this array (with bind_param) to filter my results with "WHERE ... IN ...":

```
if ($result = $link->prepare("SELECT sapp.appointment_id, sapp.time_start
    FROM ss_appointments sapp 
    WHERE sapp.service_id IN ? AND sapp.time_start >= ?
    ")) { 
                            $result->bind_param('ss', $array2, $period_from);
                            $result->execute();
                            $result->bind_result($app_id, $time_start);
                            while($result->fetch()){ 

                                echo '..results here..';

        }
```

I'm struggling with first one, so could not even check second one - if I can bind at all $array2 to string.

Hope it's clear.

Comment: `$array2 = array_keys(array_filter($array));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two parts to your question

To filter the array you can use `array_filter()`, as you are using strings, you will need to check if the value is "true" to filter out the "false" values...

```
$array2 = array_keys(array_filter($array1, function($data) { return $data == "true"; }));
```

Use `array_keys()` to get the list of indices..

The next part is building the SQL and then binding the values.  You should be building a query with the appropriate number of `?` placeholders for each value

```
SELECT sapp.appointment_id, sapp.time_start
    FROM ss_appointments sapp 
    WHERE sapp.service_id IN (?,?) AND sapp.time_start >= ?
```

also bind would then be (for example)...

```
$result->bind_param('iis', 2, 5, $period_from);
```

So it builds the `iis` data types dynamically and the list of fields to bind. These are then put in using the argument unpacking (`...`) operator...

```
// Build comma separater list of placeholders
$in = trim(str_repeat("?,", count($array2)),",");
// Create appropriate bind data type string
$type= str_repeat("i", count($array2));
$sql = "SELECT sapp.appointment_id, sapp.time_start
    FROM ss_appointments sapp 
    WHERE sapp.service_id IN (".$in.") AND sapp.time_start >= ?";
if ($result = $link->prepare($sql)) {
    // Add the period to the bind data
    $array2[] = $period_from;
    $result->bind_param($type.'s', ...$array2);
    $result->execute();
    $result->bind_result($app_id, $time_start);
    while($result->fetch()){

        echo '..results here..';

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, love your solution with dynamic list of field to bind!

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, not tested:

```
//filter out false, space and 0 and get keys
$params = array_keys(array_filter($array));

//add other variables in order of ? appearence
$params[] = $period_from;    

//create a comma separated list of ?
$list = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($params), '?'));

//use $list in the IN clause
$result = $link->prepare("SELECT sapp.appointment_id, sapp.time_start
    FROM ss_appointments sapp 
    WHERE sapp.service_id IN ($list) AND sapp.time_start >= ?";

//create types of string for each variable
$result->bind_param(str_repeat('s', count($params)), $params);
```